# SQL - Selecting value from specific column in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table called keys, and a column named keys. How do I select a specific value using SQL?

Comment: As a naming convention I use pluralis for table names (they store data about several items), and singularis for column names. E.g. table `keys`, and column `key`. (Same column name as table name is a bit confusing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    Keys 
from Keys 
where [ValueColumn] = 1234
```

Comment: Note that square brackets is a product specific construction.

Answer (score 0):

Select keys from `keys` where (insert condition)

Comment: can you write the full statement? I can't seem to get it to work.

Table: Keys
Column: Keys
Value: 1234

Comment: Select keys from keys.

Comment: The output will be all the keys value

Comment: specific value
Select keys from `keys` where keys = 1234